# Find the largest subset of unpaired elements

Tags: algorithms, optimization, np-complete, sets

I have a large list (around 200k) of element pairs `(e.g. A-B, A-C, B-C, ...)`. How can I find the largest subset of elements amongst which none are paired?

Example of pairs:

```
A-B
A-C
A-F
B-C
C-D
E-F
F-G
```

Here the largest subset would be of size 4, and one of the subsets with size 4 would be: `{A,D,E,G}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be the graph whose edges are the given pairs. Then, the problem is to find a maximum independent set in $G$.  There exist algorithms for this, but this problem is NP-hard in general.